# jQuery, which element is clicked (dynamic)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so im pretty new to jQuery.

What im trying to do:

Whenever a user is clicking an element within my ul, i want the ID of that listelement and run a function. **the li's are called like the div's with a aditional _button tag. eg.**

**div id="test1"**

**li id="test1_button"**

The current showed div-box should slide out left, the li-element, which refers to another div, should slide in right.

this is what i have so far:

```
function SH_GET_DIV() {
   $('nav ul li').each(function(){

         var SH_MENU_ELEMENTS=String($(this).attr('id'));
         var SH_BUTTONS=SH_MENU_ELEMENTS.indexOf('_button');

         if( SH_BUTTONS >= 0 ) {
            var SH_MENU_CLEARED_STRING = SH_MENU_ELEMENTS.replace('_button','');
            if( $('#'+SH_MENU_CLEARED_STRING).css('display') == 'block') {

            $('#'+SH_MENU_CLEARED_STRING).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500);

            } 
         }
         });

}
```

The function gives me the box which is currently showed, so that the script nows, which box has to slide out. **This works**

also i have this, **works**

example:

```
$('#sh_test1_button').click(function() {
      SH_GET_DIV();

      $('#sh_test').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 400);

});
```

This is pretty static, so im trying to build this a bit more dynamic.

So far i have this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'nav ul li', function () {
    $(this.id).click(function() {
      SH_GET_DIV();

      $(this.id.replace('_button','')).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 400);

});
});
```

But nothing happens when i click a li-Element.

**So my question is:**

How can i build this dynamically. I want to know which li-Element was clicked, start the **SH_GET_DIV()** function, **and let the div, which refers to the li-Element, slide in from the right**

Again:

the **li-IDs** are build like this:

**test1_button**

**test2_button**

...

the **div-IDs** are build like this

**test1**

**test2**

...

obviously **test1_button** refers to **test1** and so on..

Thanks!

Comment: Not really related... `BUT_WHY_WRITE_LIKE_THIS` ?

Comment: any console error you found in your browser? if yes then update your question with console logs. Thank you

Comment: can you create a fiddle and share what you got so far.

Comment: no, there are no erros

Comment: if you can share the code on jsfiddle then please do its easy for us to find error or share some error logs.

Comment: share some HTML DOM so we can identify pattern

Comment: thanks guys, the solution was i forgot the "#".... Also i have to close .click(function() before the slide in right-animation.

Comment: For everyone who is interested:

The final code is this:

   $(document).on('click', 'nav ul li', function (event) {
         SH_GET_DIV();
         $('#'+$(this).attr("id").replace('_button','')).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 400);
         event.stopPropagation();
   });

Otherwise it will not work the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('#'+$(this).attr("id").replace('_button','')).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 400);
```

instead of

```
$(this.id.replace('_button','')).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 400);
```

will work to you.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try to get the ID using the below code:

```
$(this).attr("id")
```

instead of

```
$(this.id)
```